# Assigning script to a variable with a variable (Unity 3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

So the title is a bit weird but i didnt know how to call it.

I am working on a FPS game and I am trying to make a simple weaponsystem. Every Player can have a primary and a secondary weapon. I am at the moment trying to write a script to change between the assigned primary/secondary weapons.

So at first I am doing this:

```js
var primary : GameObject;
var secondary : GameObject;
```

So I have some GUI Buttons that when they get clicked they assign the desired weapon to the variables primary/secondary.

An code example:

```js
function assignump45() {
    primary = ump;
}
```

Now I want to write a function to switch between the primary and secondary weapon.
So I tried this:

```js
function switchtoprimary(){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("2")){

        primary.inv(); //makes the primary weapon invisible
        secondary.vis(); //makes the primary weapon visible

    }
}
```

Of course I get this error:

> BCE0019: 'inv' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.GameObject'.

I know that what I wrote is wrong. So I tried to get the script of the primary/secondary weapons so I can disable/activate them:

```js
var primscipt : umpscript = GameObject.Find(ump).GetComponent(umpscript);
```

This works **BUT** I can´t write for every weapon this kind of script because I then I need to write several combinations of switching between the weapons and that isn´t possible because i know there is a better solution..

I can´t do a if clause and then assign the primscript because the variable only would be assigned in the if clause..

What I need is something like this (doesn´t work of course^^).

```js
var primscipt : primaryscriptstring = GameObject.Find(primarystring).GetComponent(primaryscriptstring);
```

So I could assign the variable primaryscriptstring with "umpscript" for example. the variable primarystring does work in this case

Are there any workarounds? I am pretty desperate at the moment :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to create a Weapon class, and have your `primary` and `secondary` vars be Weapons, not GameObjects.

```js
var primary : Weapon;
var secondary : Weapon;
```

Your Weapon.js file might look something like:

```js
function vis () {
    ...
}

function inv () {
    ...
}
```

Then assuming you want to have every weapon type be an extended class of Weapon, you might create a UMP.js file for example and have its class extend Weapon like so:

```js
#pragma strict

class UMP extends Weapon {

}
```

UMP then inherits all functions and vars from the Weapon class. So then, elsewhere in your code, the following line would work (assuming there's a GameObject named "UMP" somewhere that has the UMP component attached):

```js
function assignump45() {
    var ump : UMP = GameObject.Find("UMP").GetComponent(UMP);
    primary = ump;
    primary.vis();
}
```

---

Alternatively, you might not want to have every weapon type be an extended class, and just have one Weapon class for all weapons, in which case you wouldn't create a UMP.js file, and instead your code might look like:

```js
function assignump45() {
    var ump : Weapon = GameObject.Find("UMP").GetComponent(Weapon);
    primary = ump;
    primary.vis();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I just got a quick question. My function inv for example looks like this:

function vis () {
var renderers = GetComponentsInChildren(Renderer);
for (var r : Renderer in renderers) {
    r.enabled = true;
    aktiv = true;
    fakeclip.renderer.enabled = false;
}

Sometimes I need to make another object (like a second fakeclip that I use for animations) invisible but since I am now doing it over Weapon.js, how can I make the fakeclip invisible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
primary.inv();
secondary.vis();
```

do

```
primary.SetActive(false);
secondary.SetActive(true);
```

The `SetActive` method works for any game object, so you don't have to worry about the specific type of weapon or script. See the Unity docs on this [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html).